# How do I optimize a web page to rank on Google?

Tags: web, optimization

I have a website that has a lot of content on it but it doesn't rank for any keywords. It has no website traffic and I'm not sure how to get it to appear for keywords that will generate traffic and turn into leads

I hired a writer to write as much about bathroom renovations because i read Google loves content. I  have put up images and even made my domain name my main keyword: bathroomrenovationsoshawa.ca I thought that at the worst case situation the website would rank for ONE keyword! I can't find it anywahere on Google search and it's been a month or so.

Comment: Per the tag guidance for [tag:seo], SEO questions are off-topic here and belong on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -2):

There are a ton of things you can do to optimize your website. In fact, I found a resource with 50 tips on how to optimize a web page. It's a checklist you can run through and add as many elements to your page as possible.

You can find it here: https://austinbryantconsulting.com/blog/on-page-seo-checklist/

Here's another amazing resource that you have to read. It explains everything with even more detail: https://moz.com/blog/visual-guide-to-keyword-targeting-onpage-optimization

Regarding your site, [https://bathroomrenovationsoshawa.ca](https://bathroomrenovationsoshawa.ca/), since you already have the keyword in your domain name, you don't need to do much to repeat it on your homepage. Avoid keyword stuffing-which is repeating the keywords you want to rank for too many times. In your case-try to avoid your keyword altogether. This site is already going to b optimized for bathroom renovations Oshawa without listing the keyword once! In fact, you've done a great job on that but I see a lot of business owners try to force ranking by repeating the keyword when they don't see the results they want.

First off, I think there's too much unnecessary content on your home page. Try to keep the homepage limited to small summaries of the different services and products you offer. You can then take all the details about those services to internal pages.

You actually don't even have any service pages! If you can carve out the services you want to offer on separate pages, that would be a huge step in the right direction. Then you can keep your homepage less cluttered and stick to guiding your audience in the direction they need to go.

I'm actually shocked your website loads so fast! Great job there. It's one of the many ways to optimize a web page so keep that up with the pages you publish next.
[page speed insights results for bathroomrenovationsoshawa.ca](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8NyR.png)

Here's my summary advice and todo list:

Ranking on Google is a lot about establishing trust. I don't see a GMB account attached to this website. That should be your next move.

You have what's called a thin site. Carve out your services. Publish a page for each and move all that detailed content on your homepage to your service pages. This gives your website a little more depth.

*Summarize* your services on the homepage and link to those pages directly from the homepage.

Add a blog and publish once a week on past projects. You need to research keywords to use for your blog though. Don't just randomly write stuff.

I would get testimonials up and past work you've done.

List your business in as many local directories as possible and if you know other local businesses that will link to your website (vendors, clients, friends, etc) that will be a huge step in off-page optimization.

Do all of these things and you'll definitely see some movement in ranking and an increase in traffic!

Good luck!